# É correrto fazer integration test negativo?

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade, integração, postman, testes-automatizados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu caso estou usando o postman para fazer os integration tests, algo bem simples até o momento.
Porem minha duvida é, se assim como em unity teste (No caso eu ja fiz varios com MSTest c#) se é correto eu fazer integration test negativo no postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é correto independente da linguagem

> Objetivos da Atividade de Teste é executar
> um programa com a intenção de descobrir um defeito

> • Um bom caso de teste é aquele que tem uma
> elevada probabilidade de revelar um defeito
> ainda não descoberto

> • Um teste bem sucedido é aquele que revela
> um defeito ainda não descoberto

> Classe de equivalência
> − Conjunto de estados válidos e inválidos para
> condições de entrada

>  Diretrizes
> − Intervalo:
>  Uma classe válida
>  Duas classes inválidas

> PRESSMAN, R.S. Engenharia de
> Software. São Paulo: Makron Books,
> 1995. Capítulo 18. ISBN: 85-346- 0237-9.